# Cannot compile C file containing asm code with MinGW

Tags: c, assembly, gcc, inline-assembly, portable-executable

I need to compile as a 32 bit PE file a C program that has an asm snippet, the asm code is declared in this way:

```
__asm__("jz $ + $13;\n\t"
        "jnz $ + $7;\n\t"
        "emit %0xe8;\n\t");
```

When I try to compile it with MinGW, that is based on GCC, it gives me the error:

```
/tmp/ccPbXtg9.s: Assembler messages:
/tmp/ccPbXtg9.s:77: Error: operand type mismatch for `jz'
/tmp/ccPbXtg9.s:78: Error: operand type mismatch for `jnz'
/tmp/ccPbXtg9.s:79: Error: no such instruction: `emit %0xe8'
```

The command that I use to compile is

```
i686-w64-mingw32-gcc file.c -o file.exe
```

Do you know what am I doing wrong? Thank you in advance.

Comment: Try perhaps `-masm=intel`?

Comment: `$` is called `.` in gnu but that's a pretty strange way to use it given you don't even know what's gonna be at those addresses. `jz .+13` should assemble. Also there is no `emit`, you can do `.byte 0xe8` instead.

Comment: Using both your suggestions worked, thank you really much guys

Comment: jz works best with Rihanna.

Comment: There's no way this can be safe except in a `__attribute__((naked))` function, or at global scope outside any function if you're using a global basic `asm("...");` statement instead of a separate `.S` file to define a whole function.  Inside a function, there's no way to tell the compiler you want an input in ZF, and it's not safe to assume anything about what the last instruction was before an `asm` statement.  It's also not supported to jump outside an `asm` statement.  https://gcc.gnu.org/onlinedocs/gcc/Extended-Asm.html

Comment: Also, if `jz` was not taken, `jnz` could just be `jmp`, unless the `jnz` could be the target of another jump.

Comment: @Peter Corders I know that it's a strange way to use the two jumps but I'm testing anti disassembly techniques and that is one of them, thank you for your support anyway